# Adding CORS header in nginx-proxy appends the value rather than overrides it

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, jwilder-nginx-proxy

I'm trying to add a cors header using nginx proxy Docker container
https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy.

I've create a config file containing the line:

add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always

I've used a volume to pass this in through the docker-compose file at runtime so it appears at /etc/nginx/vhost.d/default

But the resulting header in the api response contains two values separated by a comma:
http://myapi-domain.com, *

This makes cross-domain requests fail with the error: header contains multiple values but only one is allowed.

Think I'm following the documentation correctly...Is this a fault or is there a way to over-ride so there's only one value in the header?

Comment: I would like to do something similar but I'm a bit lost in the doc. Can you point out the relevant page(s) ?

Comment: Also could you post the content of your file ?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else is getting CORS errors with this nginx-proxy Docker, check the logs properly as this turned out to be a max_body_size error in the nginx.   The browser saw it as a CORS error for some reason. max body size can be easily configured using the same method I used above to modify the headers